# Splitting SQL results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL statement which returns a number of rows and these are inserted into an array within VBA. I then loop through the array and paste into spreadsheet rows.

I am running out of memory, therefore I would like to do the pasting in batches.

I do not mind running the same SQL query each time to collect the data, so long as I can avoid the memory problems. How can I do this? In My SQL I used to use LIMIT, but here I want to say select the first... 1000? and then the next 1000 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it easiest to create a stored proc to call that uses a basic pagination function by passing in 2 parameters: the rows per page and requested page.

Check out this question: [How to do pagination in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008)

If you're calling the stored proc programmatically, you can use a while loop until you don't get any results back.

Answer (score 1):

To "select the first... 1000? and then the next 1000" you do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT <limit>
OFFSET <batch * limit>
```

Where limit would equal 1000 and your batch would start at 0 and increment by 1 for each call

Comment: What exactly does this do? I call the SQL code multiple times? How/what does it keep track of position with? Thanks for answering

Comment: this will get 1000 rows at a time that you can release from memory once you are done (for each batch).  You could simply do a for loop to store the batch:

limit = 1000;
for (batch = 0; batch < total_rows / limit; batch++) {
    see above
}

Comment: This is Mysql specific - OP specifies SQL Server in the question.

Comment: Yes I was after SQL Server- I just related to MySQL's LIMIT ability.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sqlserver . And make sure you have an ORDER clause so you don't get any of the same stuff twice.