# razor sql error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this razor statement

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM CarBike" +
       "Order By id OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS ;";

var result = db.Query(sql, offset, pageSize);
```

i am getting error

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'By'.
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'By'.
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
```

Please help me to correct this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space between `CarBike` and `Order by`

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM CarBike" + 
   " Order By id OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS ;";
```

NB: `OFFSET/FETCH` is SQL 2012+ only.

To achieve similar results in previous versions

```
select * from
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn
from CarBike
) v
where rn between @0+1 and @0+@1
order by id
```

Comment: now i ma getting Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Comment: i am using sql 2008 now i ma getting Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'. Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Comment: If you're using SQL2008, you can't use the SQL 2012 Offset/Fetch syntax. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: could you pls give me alternative syntax for sql 2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008