# MSSQL query not working after adding PHP variable to the LIMIT

Tags: php, sql-server, variables

This is a query that I have used successfully in a MySQL environment before.  When I try it using MSSQL.  It errors out on this statement:

```
$result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM DriverAppInfo ORDER BY appdate LIMIT $startrow, 20")
```

$startrow is defined by the following:

```
if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
  $startrow = 0;
} 
else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}
```

Does $startrow in the query need to be surrounded by single quotes?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `limit` keyword translates to [`top`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463(v=sql.90).aspx) in MSSQL / Sql Server land.

You'll need to abstract that depending on MySQL / MSSQL.  Remember:

> PDO does not provide a database abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or
>   emulate missing features. You should use a full-blown abstraction
>   layer if you need that facility.

Also I'll mention that with MSSQL depending on version `limit, offset` might not be supported.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008) for MSSQL pagination approaches.

Answer (score 0):

1) 
check `mssql_get_last_message()`

2)
show final SQL,
use somethin like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM DriverAppInfo ORDER BY appdate LIMIT $startrow, 20";
$result = mssql_query($sql);

echo $sql;
```