# How to return limited set of records from stored procedure from huge set of records?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

If a store procedure retrieves about 100 records from table then how to return 10 records each on every button click. I do not want to return all 100 records at a time. I need to return them in parts.

Comment: What database system is this? For SQL Server, the `TOP` keyword would be a way to limit the amount of data returned. For MySQL `LIMIT`, and for Oracle, there's `ROWNUM`. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2008

Comment: Try this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
set @p_start_row = @p_page_no*@p_page_size
set @p_end_row= @p_page_no*@p_page_size + @p_page_size

Select * From (Select *, RowNum() Over( Order by Col1, ...) as rowNum From MyTable) A Where A.rowNum between @p_start_row and @p_end_row
```