# Paginate with Sequelize.js at SQL 2008 (that does not support FETCH)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, express, pagination, sequelize.js

So, I'm using sequelize.js with `tedious`for mssql support. MSSQL = SQL Server 2008

Well, So there is this big table named Clientes. I have to fetch data from it, but it is quite huge so I'll have to paginate trhough

I tried the 'right way', as in the docs:

```
app.use('/clientes', function(req, res){
      var page = req.params.page || 0;
      sequelize.Clientes.findAll({limit: 30, offset: 5  }) 
       .then(function(result) {
      res.json({result: result});
    });
});
```

It should work, BUT it uses a query that is something like

`SELECT .......... from [Clientes] as [Clientes] ORDER BY [CNPJ] OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 30 ROWS ONLY;` and the SQL Server return a terrible `Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement`!

So, after lots of search, I got to a point that apparently FETCH will not work with SQL 2008. That being said (and sad) I tried to force TDS version to 7_3_A. I did this using

```
dialectOptions: {
      tdsVersion: '7_3_A'
},
```

but the query sintax did not change with this :(

I'm not sure what to do anymore.... I even will use another way instead of paginate... I found a nice sintax to SQL pagination (involving `row_number()`) , but I was not able to perform it as a raw query on sequelyze. `myModel.query('SQL QUERY HERE')` returned undefined function oO'

Any helps will be appreciated

Comment: You need to call `sequelize.query` (the sequelize instance), not `myModel.query` (model). If you have a nice limit and offset implementation feel free to post it at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues or open a pull request

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier, I'm sorry, I was wrong, i AM using sequelize.query('Select.....') and got the undefined function.. But I'll double check and let you know... Well what I have and should work is a simple SQL query that uses `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY...)`

Comment: Hey @JanAagaardMeier , I did `sequelize.query('SELECT *  FROM (SELECT t.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.cnpj) as rownum  FROM (SELECT t1.cnpj FROM Clientes t1) as t) AS u WHERE u.rownum > 5  AND u.rownum <= 10')` and got `typeError: undefined is not a function` I tried both for `require('sequelize')` and for my instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after lots of searching and debugging, I found 2 things.

1) My sequelize instance was `sequelize.sequelize`, due to a `module.exports` with lodash. My bad, I did not remember that, and did not even mention it in the question. I'm sorry about this.

2) The `offset` and `limit` do use `fetch` and thus generates invalid SQL sintax for SQL 2008.

I had to perform a raw query, using `sequelize.sequelize.query()` (since my instance was sequelize.sequelize).

> The query used for pagination in mssql 2008 was found [In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17618513/1576978):

here's my full code, including express routing and ugly format for the query:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

app.use('/tableName', function(req, res){
    var page = req.params.page || 2;
    var rowsPerPage = req.params.perpage || 30;

    if(rowsPerPage > 100){ 
        rowsPerPage = 100; //this limits how many per page
    }

    var theQuery = 'declare @rowsPerPage as bigint; '+
        'declare @pageNum as bigint;'+
        'set @rowsPerPage='+rowsPerPage+'; '+
        'set @pageNum='+page+';   '+
        'With SQLPaging As   ( '+
        'Select Top(@rowsPerPage * @pageNum) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID asc) '+
        'as resultNum, * '+
        'FROM tableName )'+
        'select * from SQLPaging with (nolock) where resultNum > ((@pageNum - 1) * @rowsPerPage);';


    sequelize.sequelize.query(theQuery) 
     .spread(function(result) {
        res.json({result: result});
      });
});
```

And if you (as I did) wonder why `sequelize.sequelize` instead of only `sequelize`?

Well, this is because `var sequelize` is a `require()` from a file with the following `module.exports`:

```
 module.exports = lodash.extend({
  sequelize: sequelize, //reffers to new Sequelize(db,user,pass,{});
  Sequelize: Sequelize
 }, db)
```

So this is why just `sequelize.query()` was returned `undefined`, and `sequelize.sequelize.query()` works fine, because in true my `sequelize` variable is an Object with the `sequelize` property being the real sequelize connection instance.