# How to get top 10 row next time next 10 row and so on in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with 1000 rows, and I have a procedure that is called after every two mints, I want to get first ten rows (1-10) for the first time, second time next ten rows (11-20) 3rd time next ten rows (21-30) and so on to 1000th row.

Comment: Please Google for this and search Stack Overflow; it's been answered dozens of times.

Comment: How do you determine which ones are the first ten rows? Please post your table structure and how the rows need to be ordered

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2007** - we have SQL Server 7.0, 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 - which one is it really?

Comment: *first ten rows* - order by what? If you want to get the *first* or *next* rows, you must have some ordering - what are you ordering by? Can you show us the table structure, and your stored procedure code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do pagination in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: sorry, actually i have SQL 2008 R2

Comment: and i want to order the table on id column

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure with '@PageNumber, @PageSize' as parameters to implement 'Pagination' functionality

[Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008?rq=1)