# How can we do pagination in fetching the value with 100 records each in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

How can we do fetching first 100 records next 100 records then next and so on in SQl Server from a table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do pagination in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **CTE** and **OFFSET**:

```
@RecordIndex=Start Row No
@PageSize=No of Rows to fetch

;WITH CTE_Results
AS (
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS ROWNUM,
    Count(*) over () AS TotalCount,
    *
    FROM TableName  
)      
Select * from CTE_Results 
ORDER BY ROWNUM
OFFSET (@RecordIndex) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Yes it indicate starting row index , if you wants from 1 to 10 then pass 1, if you wants from 11 to 20 then pass 11 and so on

Comment: is it 11 or 2 /  we should record index as 2 s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the procedure that will give you pagination based on the page number and the record count. By default the procedure will return first 100 records from your table.

1. Create the below procedure in your database. Make sure you have mention the name of your table and ordering column.

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fetchdata]
       @pageno INT=1,
       @pagesize INT=100
   AS
   BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON;    

   DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)= '    
               SELECT *
               FROM YOURTABLE
               ORDER BY [YOURCOLUMN]
               OFFSET ('+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@pageno)+' - 1) * '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@pagesize)
                   +' ROWS FETCH NEXT '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@pagesize)+' ROWS ONLY;'

    EXEC (@sql)


    END
   ```
2. use the below script to execute the procedure,with page number and page size as input.

   ```
     EXEC [FetchData] @pageno=2 ,@pagesize=100
   ```

Comment: here ,OFFSET ('+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@pageno)+' - 1) * '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@pagesize)
                +' ROWS FETCH NEXT '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@pagesize)+' ROWS ONLY;' it showinf the error

Comment: could you please explain what  is the exact error that you are getting?? In this procedure you have to pass the page number and the page size,ie. the number of rows that you want from the table.

Comment: means it shoing error near off set , now it is correct beacuse i put ',' before offset it was the pblm

Comment: by using the  VARCHAR(MAX)= it will take more time to fetch or not?

Comment: nope ,its just storing the query string.. fetching will take place in the next step.. EXEC(@sql)

Answer (score 0):

Using row_number...

```
;with cte
as
(
select *,row_number() over (order by someuniquekey) as paging
)
select * from where paging between 1 and 100
```

you could also use Offset and Fetch like below,,

```
select 
* from table
order by someuniquekey
offset 0 rows fetch next 100 rows only
```

Parameterized version of above ..

```
-- parameterized
DECLARE 
  @pagenum  AS INT = 2,
  @pagesize AS INT = 100;

SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY someuniquekey
OFFSET (@pagenum - 1) * @pagesize ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY;
```

**Further reading..**
http://sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-2012-t-sql-glance-offsetfetch

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this page for your reference, it is same question related to paginatin

[How to do pagination in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008)