# How to write SQL query for pagination in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

Can you help me write SQL sentence that choose many rows ? It is about pagination - parameters are size of page (=number of rows in one bucket) and number of page to choose (many rows = size of page).

For me, it should look like:
`cnt =select count(*) from table`
`select * from table limit x,y`
`x=cnt/size_of_page * number_of_page`
`y=(cnt/size_of_page * number_of_page)+size_of_page`

I am not sure if I am correct. Can you help me with translating it into sql server ?

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: I need for 2008 and 2015 version

Comment: pagination for 2008 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008 ... for 2015 `OFFSET` and `FETCH` were introduced, which behave similarly to `LIMIT` in MySQL and Postgres.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Comment: I don't think there is a version called 2015 in sql server. there is 2012, 2014 and 2016, there is also 2005, but I've never heard of 2015. Also, `limit` is used in MySql, not in Sql Server, are you sure you are asking about the correct database?

Comment: Yes, I was not correct. I meant 2016 version