# Pagination in Sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server, pagination

I have used opencsv libray to write the ResultSet in a csv file,using the writeAll method.Since the database is very big i have to split database records and write them to different csv files(For example every 1000 rows must be written in different files.) I have read about this but i havent suceded.I have used something like

```
select * from table1
Order by id
OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

but it doesnt work.Can someone tell me how to achieve this please?

Comment: Can you explain doesn't work? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Do you get incorrect results? There are dozens if not hundreds or even thousands of examples of how to do this all over the internet.

Comment: It throws a NullPointerException when trying to write the  ResultSet in the file

Comment: did you miss `ROW(S)` after `OFFSET 0`, or just a typo

Comment: I missed but still the same

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
select * from table1
Order by id
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you are using SQL server 2008, these features (Offset/Fetch) are from SQL server 2012 onwards.

Comment: Well is there another way i can achieve something like this?

Comment: There are very good methods provided in the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244322/how-to-do-pagination-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

If somebody else needs it :

```
WITH CTEResults AS
(
    SELECT IDColumn, SomeField, DateField, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateField) AS RowNum
    FROM MyTable
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTEResults
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```